# How to obtain the physical id of a pthread in C

Tags: c, pthreads, multicore

How can I obtain the physical id and the core id of the current processor on which the pthread is running?

Answer (score 2):

By and large you can't do this in a meaningful way. You might be pre-empted by the scheduler mid way through asking the question and resume on a different processor.

Answer (score 2):

There is no portable way. If you use GNU/Linux, you can try function `sched_getcpu`.

Comment: Actually I didn't read your question carefully before answering it.. `shced_getcpu` only returns the logical id. I think you will need to look it up in /proc/cpuinfo to get the physical information (physical CPU, core, hyperthreading etc).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible because thread is running not by a single processor but by a schedule, which ever processor is free at that time will take the job for some amount of time then save the data, then another processor may take that job.

Comment: But won't the OS try to make sure there is core affinity at best i.e. as much as possible try to run the thread on the same core it ran before so that it does not have to clear the TLB etc associated with that thread ? Else there will be lots of TLB misses right ? At least in Linux a thread is seen more or less as a process.

Comment: @David and stacker are just pointing out that returned results are stale and may no longer be valid.  The OS scheduler will make whatever optimizations it can but, if a user clicks on a browser link and dumps a dozen ready threads onto the system at once during your 'what core' call, your thread TLB cache stuff will be long gone by the time it runs again and it could pop up on any core.